# Changing the epsilon in a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am working through a Real Analysis book on my own and have come across the proof of the equivalence relation between two Cauchy sequences, and have a question regarding transitivity.

If we let $x_1,x_2,...$,$y_1,y_2,...$ and $z_1,z_2,...$ be Cauchy sequences of rationals such that the $x-y$ and $y-z$ pairs are equivalent, then we can use the triangle inequality as follows:

For some $\epsilon > 0$ we have an $m$ such that for all $k \geq m$ the following holds:

$|x_k - z_k| \leq |x_k - y_k| + |y_k - z_k| < \epsilon + \epsilon = 2\epsilon$

Now, the way I have seen it is to let both $|x_k - y_k|$ and $|y_k - z_k|$ be less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ so that we have:

$|x_k - z_k| \leq |x_k - y_k| + |y_k - z_k| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

I am confused with how we can freely change between these two methods. Is it because our $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and our $m$ is based off of this said $\epsilon$? Is there a simple algebraic step between the two I am missing, or is it just that our $\epsilon$ can be anything so we have just have to let our $m$ shift accordingly?

Comment: Yes, $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real, and yes, $m$ depends on $\epsilon$. Also, it's not "for some $\epsilon > 0$"; rather, it's "for _any_ $\epsilon > 0$,

Comment: Ahh, thank you. You're right, I should have been more precise with my wording. That distinction between universal and existential quantifiers is important.

Comment: As my professor would say, "It's the same amongst friends."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0,$ they need $|x_k-z_k|<\epsilon,$ so they made $|x_k-y_k|$ and $|y_k-z_k|$ smaller than $\epsilon/2$ for convenience. This way at the end they get $|x_k-z_k|<\epsilon$ and not $|x_k-z_k|<2\epsilon.$

Here is the justification: For each $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $m$ such that for all $k\geq m$ we have $|x_k-y_k|<\epsilon$ and $|y_k-z_k|<\epsilon.$

Thus, given $\epsilon>0,$ we can let $\epsilon'=\epsilon/2.$ Then $\epsilon'>0$ as well, so there exists $m$ such that for all $k\geq m$ we have $|x_k-y_k|<\epsilon'=\epsilon/2$ and $|y_k-z_k|<\epsilon'=\epsilon/2.$

Comment: And, to be pedantic, you need $m_1$ that gives us $k\ge m_1\implies |x_k-y_k|<\epsilon/2$ and $m_2$ that gives us $k\ge m_2\implies |y_k-z_k|<\epsilon/2$. Then you set $m=\max(m_1,m_2)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right.